# Auto Format Masterpage in Visual Studio

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, master-page

I am creating a custom master page in visual studio. I inherited this from another developer who has not learnt how to indent code properly. One thing that I have noticed that seems it is not possible to collapse code when editing a master page. Is there a way that I can auto format the code to that I get the correct indentation?

In the past I have used

> (ctrl+k, ctrl+d)

but this does not seem to work...

Comment: I have master pages in two places in my VS solution: some in a Module, and some in a subdirectory of the mapped Layouts directory. Curiously, the master in Layouts supports things like Auto Format, collapsing elements, and the little drop-down boxes at the top of the file for "Server Objects & Events", but the masters in the Module do not. If your Master isn't in the Layouts directory, you could move it there, try Auto Formatting, and move it back...

Comment: If I open it from layouts it works. Very strange...

Comment: That *is* weird. I actually prefer the less-functional version because I find the auto-closing tags annoying :) Maybe someone can answer this question with *why* one is functional and the other isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting worked for me for the past when you rightlick the .master (or .ASPX/.ASCX) page in VS.NET and explicitly select "Master Page Editor". It seems its default but somehow still explicitly needed to be selected.

Comment: +1, this works for me as well. Again, default, but only works if you pick it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, check for the XHTML Validation errors using VS studio 2010 OR SharePoint Designer 2010 ( green underlines... etc). Correct them and the (ctrl+k, ctrl+d) should work fine.